# How to prevent JSESSIONID cookie from being encoded in HTTP request header

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, httprequest, jsessionid

I have tried my level best to resolve this but the issue persists.

I make an API call, via HTTP, to a Tomcat server which authenticates the credentials and returns a JSESSIONID cookie in the response. The JSESSIONID cookie value looks something like this: `4B9F86D951ABA52BB3507CE06852C34C.fe1`. To authenticate the next API call, I have to grab this value and send it across with the request object.

The issue is the above value gets converted to:
`4B9F86D951ABA52BB3507CE06852C34C%2Efe1`. As you can see, the cookie value is encoded and the dot [.] converted to `%2E`. This is causing authentication to fail repeatedly.

Kindly advice on how to resolve this issue!

Comment: (Edit) Please post your code. According to [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d85.html), <cfhttpparam type="header" ...> should NOT be encoded by default, but `type="cookie"` IS encoded. You could probably use either one, but we need to see your code to know what you are currently using. (Though I am not sure why it would normal url encoding would cause an issue...)

Comment: Gah, that last line should read "*.. not sure why normal url encoding would cause an issue*"

Answer (score 0):

Use `UrlDecode()` function to decode the value. And pass the `CharSet` parameter to it which in your case should be `utf-8`.

```
<cfset jsessionid = UrlDecode( '4B9F86D951ABA52BB3507CE06852C34C%2Efe1', 'utf-8' )>
<cfdump var = "#jsessionid #">
```

Comment: Hey Pankaj. I am sending the cookie via cfhttpparam which actually URL encodes the JSESSIONID value. Any idea how t get around it?